# contents in animation does not apears completely css

Tags: html, css

I am working with front end where an html page contains some content which would be appeared as a marquee tag which is deprecated. so I used css to achieve this. but every long string in this area does not appears completely rather a part of string get displayed according to the screen.

here is my html code, please suggest a solution for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style style="type/css">
            .example1 {
                height: 50px;
                overflow:hidden;
                position:relative;
            }
            .example1 h3 {
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                position: inherit;
                width: 100%;
                height: 20px;
                margin: 0;
/*              line-height: 50px;
*/              text-align: center;
                /* Starting position */
                -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
                -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
                transform:translateX(100%);
                /* Apply animation to this element */  
                -moz-animation: 10s linear 0s infinite alternate none example1;
                -webkit-animation: 10s linear 0s infinite alternate none example1;
                animation: 10s linear 0s infinite alternate none example1;
            }
            /* Move it (define the animation) */
            @-moz-keyframes example1 {
                from { margin-left:-20%; }
                to { margin-left:100%; }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes example1 {
                from { margin-left:-20%; }
                to { margin-left:100%; }
            }
            @keyframes example1 {
                0%   {  -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
                        transform: translateX(100%);         
                }
                100% {  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
                        transform: translateX(-100%); 
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="example1">
            <h3>
                 Premium   400 ml  .. Molecule Brew 1600 ml .. Dark Roasted 1600 ml  .. Molecule Brew  400 ml .. Wheat Beer  1600ml    .. Premium 1600  ml  .. Dark Roasted 550 ml   .. Dark Roasted 400 ml   .. Wheat Beer 400 ml .. Wheat Beer 550 ml .. Jack Daniels Honey 360 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 30 ML    .. Absolut Elyx 30 ML    .. Jack Daniels Honey 750 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 360 ML   .. Absolut Elyx 360 ML   .. Ciroc 750 ML  .. Ciroc 360 MI  .. Belvedere 30Ml    .. Grey Goose 750 Ml .. Absolut Elyx 750 ML   .. Grey Goose 30 Ml  .. woodford reserve 30 Ml    .. Grey Goose 360Ml  .. Ciroc 30 Ml   .. Belvedere 750 Ml  .. Belvedere 360 Ml  .. woodford reserve 750  Ml  .. woodford reserve 360 Ml   .. SULA  Red BOTTLE  750 ML  .. Sula Red 150 ML   .. opera 150 ML  .. Woodbridge Red 750 ML .. Natana Cuvee Blanche 150 ML   .. Natana Cuvee Blanche 750 ML   .. Jacob Creek Chardonnay 150 ML .. opera 750 ML  . Jacob Creek Chardonnay 750 ML  Bottle .. Woodbridge Red 150 ML .. sangria white  Glass  .. sangria Red  pitcher  .. sangria white   pitcher   .. sangria Red  Glass    .. sula brut .. Jacobs Creek Brut .. Moet & chandon    .. sambuca 30 ml .. kahlua 30 ml  .. xenta absinthe 30 ml  .. campari 30 ml .. malibu 30 ml  . bailey's irish cream 30 ml    .. amaretto 30 ml    .. patron xo caf' 30 ml  .. Jagermeister 30 ml    .. calvados 30 ml    .. Glenmorangie original .. glenfiddich 12 yrs 30 ml  .. SINGLETON 10YRs   .. glenlivet 12 yrs 30 ml    .. glenlivet 15 yrs 30 ml    .. TALISKER 10YRS 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 12 yrs Bottle   .. Glenfiddich 12 yrs Bottlel    .. glenfiddich 18 yrs 30 ml  .. Aberlour 12 yrs 30 ml .. CARDHU 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 15 yrs Bottle   .. OBAN 14YRS 30 ml  .. glenfiddich 15 yrs 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 18 yrs Bottle   .. SINGLETON 10YRs Bottle    .. LAGAVULIN 16YRS 30 ml .. glenlivet 18 yrs 30 ml    .. Glenmorangie original Bottle  .. Glenfiddich 18 yrs Bottle .. OBAN 14YRS Bottle .. Glenfiddich 15 yrs Bottle .. LAGAVULIN 16YRS Bottle    .. CHASER    .. Tonic water   .. Canned juice  .. Sprite    .. Molecule Brew  550 ml .. Kingfisher Premium 330 ml .. Kingfisher Premium 6 pints    .. Kingfisher Premium 12 pints   .. Breezer 330 ml    .. Breezer 6 pints   .. kingfisher ultra 330 ml   .. Breezer 12 pints  .. Budweiser 330 ml  .. kingfisher ultra 6pints   .. kingfisher ultra 12 pints .. Budweiser 12 pints    .. Budweiser 6pints  .. Amstel light  6 pints .. corona extra 6 pints  .. corona extra 12 pints .. corona extra 330 ml   .. Amstel light 330 Ml   .. Hoeggarden 6 pints    .. Hoeggarden 330 Ml .. Hoeggarden 12 pints   .. stella artois 6 Pints .. Amstel light 12 pints .. stella artois 12 Pints    .. stella artois 330 ML  .. BP Reserve Collection 30 Ml   .. Old Monk 360 Ml   .. Smirnoff 30 Ml    .. Old Monk 750 Ml   .. Old Monk 30 Ml    . Blender's Pride 750 Ml    .. Blender's Pride 360 Ml    .. BP Reserve Collection 360 Ml  .. Blender's Pride 30 Ml .. BP Reserve Collection 750 Ml  .. Smirnoff 360 ML   .. Bacardi White rum 360 Ml  .. 100 pipers 360 ML .. Teacher's Highland 750 ML .. Black Dog 8 yrs 750  ML   .. Black Dog 8 yrs 360 ML    .. Smirnoff  750  Ml .. Teacher's Highland 30 ML  .. Bacardi White rum 750 ML  .. Bacardi White rum 30 Ml   .. William Lawson 360 ML .. Black Dog 8 yrs 30 ML .. William Lawson 750 ML .. Teacher's Highland 360 ML .. William Lawson 30 ML  .. 100 pipers 30 ML  .. Blackdog 12 yrs 30 ML .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 750 ML  .. 100 pipers 750 ML .. Blackdog 12 yrs 750 ML    .. Jim Beam 750 ML   .. Jim Beam 30 ML    .. Blackdog 12 yrs 360 ML    .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 30 ML   .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 360 ML  .. Jim Beam 360 ML   .. Ketel One 30 ML   .. Ketel One 360 ML  .. Ketel One 750 ML  .. Absolut 30  ML    .. Absolut 360  ML   .. J&B Rare 360 ML   .. J&B Rare 750 ML   .. JW Red label 750ML    .. BANTINES Finest750 ML .. Jameson 30 ml .. Absolut 750 ML    .. JW Red label 30 ML    .. JW Red label 360ML    .. J&B Rare 30 ML    .. Jameson 360 ml    .. BANTINES Finest30 ML  .. Jameson 750 ml    .. BANTINES Finst  360 ml    .. JW Black Label 30 ml  .. JW Black Label 360 ml .. JW Double Black 360 ML    .. JW Double Black 30 ML .. JW Black Label 750 ML .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 30 ML  .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 360 ML .. JW Double Black 750 ML    .. Jack Daniels Honey 30 ML  .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 750 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 750 ML text..........................
            </h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its because the translateX property at 100% is less then the width of the text. The animation stops when the translate property reaches -100% ( starting from the first letter of the h3)

Comment: @hunzaboy , thanks for the reply. can you tell what should be the right value for string varying in length.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your text is very long so you have to use a bigger negative value. I am showing the below with text-indent.

http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/aJLoQx

```
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  /*              line-height: 50px;
*/
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  animation: example1 120s linear alternate;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@keyframes example1 {
  from {
    text-indent: 100%
  }
  to {
    text-indent: -2311%
  }
}
```

```css
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  /*              line-height: 50px;
*/
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  animation: example1 150s linear alternate;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@keyframes example1 {
  from {
    text-indent: 100%
  }
  to {
    text-indent: -2311%
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="example1">
            <h3>
                 Premium   400 ml  .. Molecule Brew 1600 ml .. Dark Roasted 1600 ml  .. Molecule Brew  400 ml .. Wheat Beer  1600ml    .. Premium 1600  ml  .. Dark Roasted 550 ml   .. Dark Roasted 400 ml   .. Wheat Beer 400 ml .. Wheat Beer 550 ml .. Jack Daniels Honey 360 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 30 ML    .. Absolut Elyx 30 ML    .. Jack Daniels Honey 750 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 360 ML   .. Absolut Elyx 360 ML   .. Ciroc 750 ML  .. Ciroc 360 MI  .. Belvedere 30Ml    .. Grey Goose 750 Ml .. Absolut Elyx 750 ML   .. Grey Goose 30 Ml  .. woodford reserve 30 Ml    .. Grey Goose 360Ml  .. Ciroc 30 Ml   .. Belvedere 750 Ml  .. Belvedere 360 Ml  .. woodford reserve 750  Ml  .. woodford reserve 360 Ml   .. SULA  Red BOTTLE  750 ML  .. Sula Red 150 ML   .. opera 150 ML  .. Woodbridge Red 750 ML .. Natana Cuvee Blanche 150 ML   .. Natana Cuvee Blanche 750 ML   .. Jacob Creek Chardonnay 150 ML .. opera 750 ML  . Jacob Creek Chardonnay 750 ML  Bottle .. Woodbridge Red 150 ML .. sangria white  Glass  .. sangria Red  pitcher  .. sangria white   pitcher   .. sangria Red  Glass    .. sula brut .. Jacobs Creek Brut .. Moet & chandon    .. sambuca 30 ml .. kahlua 30 ml  .. xenta absinthe 30 ml  .. campari 30 ml .. malibu 30 ml  . bailey's irish cream 30 ml    .. amaretto 30 ml    .. patron xo caf' 30 ml  .. Jagermeister 30 ml    .. calvados 30 ml    .. Glenmorangie original .. glenfiddich 12 yrs 30 ml  .. SINGLETON 10YRs   .. glenlivet 12 yrs 30 ml    .. glenlivet 15 yrs 30 ml    .. TALISKER 10YRS 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 12 yrs Bottle   .. Glenfiddich 12 yrs Bottlel    .. glenfiddich 18 yrs 30 ml  .. Aberlour 12 yrs 30 ml .. CARDHU 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 15 yrs Bottle   .. OBAN 14YRS 30 ml  .. glenfiddich 15 yrs 30 ml  .. Glenlivet 18 yrs Bottle   .. SINGLETON 10YRs Bottle    .. LAGAVULIN 16YRS 30 ml .. glenlivet 18 yrs 30 ml    .. Glenmorangie original Bottle  .. Glenfiddich 18 yrs Bottle .. OBAN 14YRS Bottle .. Glenfiddich 15 yrs Bottle .. LAGAVULIN 16YRS Bottle    .. CHASER    .. Tonic water   .. Canned juice  .. Sprite    .. Molecule Brew  550 ml .. Kingfisher Premium 330 ml .. Kingfisher Premium 6 pints    .. Kingfisher Premium 12 pints   .. Breezer 330 ml    .. Breezer 6 pints   .. kingfisher ultra 330 ml   .. Breezer 12 pints  .. Budweiser 330 ml  .. kingfisher ultra 6pints   .. kingfisher ultra 12 pints .. Budweiser 12 pints    .. Budweiser 6pints  .. Amstel light  6 pints .. corona extra 6 pints  .. corona extra 12 pints .. corona extra 330 ml   .. Amstel light 330 Ml   .. Hoeggarden 6 pints    .. Hoeggarden 330 Ml .. Hoeggarden 12 pints   .. stella artois 6 Pints .. Amstel light 12 pints .. stella artois 12 Pints    .. stella artois 330 ML  .. BP Reserve Collection 30 Ml   .. Old Monk 360 Ml   .. Smirnoff 30 Ml    .. Old Monk 750 Ml   .. Old Monk 30 Ml    . Blender's Pride 750 Ml    .. Blender's Pride 360 Ml    .. BP Reserve Collection 360 Ml  .. Blender's Pride 30 Ml .. BP Reserve Collection 750 Ml  .. Smirnoff 360 ML   .. Bacardi White rum 360 Ml  .. 100 pipers 360 ML .. Teacher's Highland 750 ML .. Black Dog 8 yrs 750  ML   .. Black Dog 8 yrs 360 ML    .. Smirnoff  750  Ml .. Teacher's Highland 30 ML  .. Bacardi White rum 750 ML  .. Bacardi White rum 30 Ml   .. William Lawson 360 ML .. Black Dog 8 yrs 30 ML .. William Lawson 750 ML .. Teacher's Highland 360 ML .. William Lawson 30 ML  .. 100 pipers 30 ML  .. Blackdog 12 yrs 30 ML .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 750 ML  .. 100 pipers 750 ML .. Blackdog 12 yrs 750 ML    .. Jim Beam 750 ML   .. Jim Beam 30 ML    .. Blackdog 12 yrs 360 ML    .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 30 ML   .. 100 pipers 12 yrs 360 ML  .. Jim Beam 360 ML   .. Ketel One 30 ML   .. Ketel One 360 ML  .. Ketel One 750 ML  .. Absolut 30  ML    .. Absolut 360  ML   .. J&B Rare 360 ML   .. J&B Rare 750 ML   .. JW Red label 750ML    .. BANTINES Finest750 ML .. Jameson 30 ml .. Absolut 750 ML    .. JW Red label 30 ML    .. JW Red label 360ML    .. J&B Rare 30 ML    .. Jameson 360 ml    .. BANTINES Finest30 ML  .. Jameson 750 ml    .. BANTINES Finst  360 ml    .. JW Black Label 30 ml  .. JW Black Label 360 ml .. JW Double Black 360 ML    .. JW Double Black 30 ML .. JW Black Label 750 ML .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 30 ML  .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 360 ML .. JW Double Black 750 ML    .. Jack Daniels Honey 30 ML  .. Chivas Regal 12yrs 750 ML .. Gentlemen's Jack 750 ML text..........................
            </h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: hi, in your answer I just run the code snippet and in last it stop moving

Comment: You have to add the infinite property to the animation.